# calling python script from php not working as desired

Tags: php

I have simple php code below where I enter value and submit button it runs the php code. The table truncate and new value is being stored as desired but I am not able to execute the python script in it.

```
<form action="" method="post">
Twittersearch: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
<input type="Submit">
</form>



<?php

$name = $_POST['name'];
$namesearch = $_POST['namesearch'];



    # Database Access
    $servername = 'localhost';
    $username = 'a';
    $password = 'a';
    $dbname = 'a';

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
    $sql = "TRUNCATE TABLE `abc`";
    #$sql = "INSERT INTO `abc`(`searchstring`, `handle`) VALUES ('".$name."','".$namesearch."')";   
    $sql = "UPDATE `abc` SET `searchstring` = '".$name."', `handle` = 'TEST' WHERE `searchstring` <> '12rm012m101101mkl'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    echo "Put ".$customerName." into ".$clusterName." successfully!";
    $command = escapeshellcmd('C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\twitterhandle.py');
    $output = shell_exec($command);
    echo $output;

?>
```

Comment: Your file is outside of your website root and you won't be able to access it. You need to reference Python relative to the project, and may need to move the Python executable itself.

Comment: Hello Martin, Obsidian Age is correct. I'm not sure how it goes in Windows, but make sure you can run Python scripts anywhere on your machine; like having the python program in your $PATH, then move that python script into your website root folder and call the same function, `escapeshellcmd()` with the python script path as it's parameter to run the script

Comment: thank you so I will move my py script to this php folder , I have already added the python exe in env variables.

Comment: that was it placed the py files under my php folder and it works thanks a lot